# Show that $X$ and diagonal $D \subset X \times X$ is homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**: Given that $(X, \tau)$ a topological space, let $D = \{(x,x)
 \subset X \times X: x \in X\}$ be the diagonal on $X \times X$, show
 that $X$ is homeomorphic to $D$ with subspace topology inherited from $X \times X$

**Can anyone provide a sketch as to how this can be done?**

My thought is to first established a homeomorphism between $X$ and $X \times X$, then show that the homeomorphism restricted to the subspace $D \subset X \times X$ is still a homeomorphism, thereby establishing that $X$ is homeomorphic to $D$. Actually now I think it is not do able since $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What is the most natural map that springs to your mind?

Comment: Note that in $X \times X$, you have points like $(x,y), x \neq y$.

Comment: Make sure you know that the diagonal is $D = \{(x,x) \in X\times X \; | \; x \in X\}$.  Your comment about $\mathbb{R}$ not being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not totally revealing: $\mathbb{R}$ is certainly homeomorphic to the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\varphi \colon X \to D \subset X \times X$ given by $x \mapsto (x, x)$ is manifestly a bijection - if you're not convinced, prove this! The inverse map $\varphi^{-1}$ projects the pair $(x, x)$ to $x \in X$. The preimage of any open subset $U$ of $X$ under $\varphi^{-1}$ is the intersection of $U \times U$ with $D$, and hence is open in the subspace topology on $D$. Can you reason similarly to see that $\varphi$ is continuous?